# Install all needed node modules inside Docker container, not just copying them

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, node-modules

The problem is the following. We have a project with several services running with docker compose.
When one of us adds a new module with `npm install <module name> --save`, the package*.json files are going to be updated and the module is going to be installed in the node_module folder.
Here, running `docker-compose up --build` everything works fine.
Nevertheless, when someone else pulls the updated versions of the package*.json files and tries to run `docker-compose up --build` Docker outputs the error that the module is not found.
It seems like the local node_module folder is copied directly into the Docker container.

The question is how can we make it possible that all needed node modules which are in the package*.json files are going to be installed inside the container not just copied?

Here is one DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm run devStart
```

as well as the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  list-service:
    build:
      context: ./list-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4041"
    volumes:
      - ./list_service:/usr/src/app
      #- /usr/src/app/node_modules
  
  user-service:
    build:
      context: ./user_service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4040"
    volumes:
      - ./user_service:/usr/src/app
     # - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  api-gateway:
    build:
      context: ./api_gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./api_gateway:/usr/src/app
     # - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  date_list-service:
    build:
      context: ./date_list_service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "4042"
    volumes:
      - ./date_list_service:/usr/src/app
    #  - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27018
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
  
volumes:
  data:
```

We do have already a .dockerignore file:

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

## Update

@DazWilkin recognized that we mount our context into the container. This overrides the images content with local content. We do this because we use nodemon. Therefore, we can see changes in the code on the fly. Is there a possibility to exclude the node_modules directory from this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is that Docker is caching layers and not detecting the changed `package*.json`.

What happens if everyone `docker-compose up --build --no-cache`?

> **NOTE** because you're running `npm install` in the container image build, you don't need (and probably don't want) to `npm install` on the host beforehand

> **NOTE** Since you're using containers, you may want to use a container registry too. That way, once the first updated docker images have been built, everyone else can pull these from the registry rather than rebuild them for themselves.

#### Update

I just noticed that you're mounting your `context` in container; you don't want to do that. It will override the work you've done building the container:

```
version: "3"
services:
  list-service:
    build:
      context: ./list-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4041"
    volumes:
      - ./list_service:/usr/src/app <<< ---- DELETE
      #- /usr/src/app/node_modules
  
  user-service:
    build:
      context: ./user_service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4040"
    volumes:
      - ./user_service:/usr/src/app <<< ---- DELETE
     # - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  api-gateway:
    build:
      context: ./api_gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./api_gateway:/usr/src/app <<< ---- DELETE
     # - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  date_list-service:
    build:
      context: ./date_list_service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "4042"
    volumes:
      - ./date_list_service:/usr/src/app <<< ---- DELETE
    #  - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27018
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
  
volumes:
  data:
```

Comment: Even if I delete all images and run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose build`, the module will not be found.
Sometimes we are running these services with without docker, so we need the node_modules local.
It seems like Docker just copies the node_modules instead of installing them.

Comment: Curious. Does the issue occur on multiple machines or just one?

Comment: Oh, hang on... I now see that you're mounting the `context` into the container

Comment: It occurs on multiple machines.

Comment: I've updated my answer.... You shouldn't mount the context into the container. By doing so, you overwrite the image's contents with your local (host's) content. That's not what you want to do. The image contains the a replica of the context that's been built into an image. Your images are built with e.g. `WORKDIR /usr/src/app` and then you e.g. overwrite that with the local host's content. Don't do that.

Comment: I see. We do that because we use nodemon. Local changes are seen directly without rebuilding. Is there a possibility to exclude the node_module directory?

Comment: That is an anti-pattern. If (some hash of) your code changes, you should build a different image. One common approach is to use e.g. GitHub Actions to rebuild images on every git commit|push. Docker images are best thought of as a distribution mechanism. There's little (no?) benefit in developing within a container image because you break a tenet of reproducible builds (as you're finding out)